# xfce4-panel 4.12.0 problem

Tags: xfce-panel

I've made an update on xenial and since my menu bar is odd :

It's one line from the top , and all windows are behind the bar.

[image]

How to correct that please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on the menu bar then go to panel then panel preferences .. uncheck the `lock panel` checkbox ..on the very left of the panel there is a spot where you can click and move/drag the panel where you want then recheck the `lock panel` checkbox .. that should solve your problem
[image]

Comment: Thanks but the windows are still behind the bar ...

Comment: I would make the browser window smaller .. then close it .. then make sure the bar is all the way to the top of the window .. then open the browser again and try to maximize the browser window .. it may be saving the last window position and that is why its still behind the bar

Comment: or maybe try messing a bit with the number of rows so that it changes the size of the bar .. then try it . and if it seems fixed then you can resize it back to the one row like you originally had it set ... maybe it will force it to reinitialize and  start working as it used too